# iOS native-like PWA with CAS authentication flow gets blocked in Safari

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, progressive-web-apps

I work on a web app which uses SSO with an external CAS server. The flow is:

1. When accessing the webapp (myapp.com), the user is redirected to a form (whereareyoufrom.com/form) which redirects to the correct CAS server login page (iamfromhere.com/login).
2. The user logs in the CAS server login page (iamfromhere.com/login).
3. The user is redirected to the webapp.

An Android app encapsulating the webapp was created using PWABuilder, which works fine.

The same encapsulated webapp was created on iOS also with PWABuilder, which creates a native Swift app with a WebView that allows to load a PWA within a native iOS application. But the authentication workflow does not work properly.

I can access the CAS server's login page (iamfromhere.com/login) correctly within the iOS app. However, when submitting the form, the a new window opens in Safari -outside of the iOS app it seems- and shows the same login page again (iamfromhere.com/login).

If I try to submit the form again I'm redirected to the identity provider website as correctly logged in (iamfromhere.com/home), instead of being redirected to the iOS app (myapp.com/home).
If I close the browser window, I'm back to the iOS app on the first iamfromhere.com/login.

[Here is a diagram of the flow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLMTX.png)
Solid green arrows for what works correctly, dashed green arrows for the expected behavior and blue arrows for what happens and is not expected.

The `manifest.json` file has `display` set to `standalone`.
The encapsulated PWA deployment target is iOS 13.
The behaviour was encountered on Xcode simulator iPhone 15 pro - iOS 17, real iPhone 13 with iOS 17 and iPad 5th generation with iPadOs 16.7.4.

I have no expertise on PWAs and iOS but what I tried and did not work:

1. In the `WebView.swift` file, set `config.limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains` to `false`
2. Adding `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` in my `index.html`
3. Adding all external domain names to the PWA's permitted URLs

**EDIT:**
I managed to make the authentication flow work by adding the domain iamfromhere.com to `authOrigins` in `Settings.swift` AND `WKAppBoundDomains` in `Info.plist`.
However, the app still opens as a duplicate in a new window in Safari.